# How to add prefix to each word in a given string

Tags: java, regex, string, string-formatting, string-prefix

I want to add prefix to every word in a given string. My code is :-

```
StringBuilder strColsToReturns  = new StringBuilder();
String strPrefix                = "abc.";
strColsToReturns.append(String.format(" %sId, %sname, %stype,", strPrefix, strPrefix, strPrefix));
```

This is fine, for small string, but I have a very large static string like this. So, this method of adding string prefix looks like a tedious method. Is there any other sophisticated way to achieve this.

Comment: Put each word in a `String[]` and then iterate over that list to prefix each element ?

Comment: Java 8 introduced the StringJoiner, where you can add a prefix.. looked at it ?

Comment: @MrSimpleMind but that prefix is added only before *first* element, not before *every* element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `replaceAll(regex, replacement)`. As regex we may want to select place which has

- space or start of string before it
- and non-space after it.

(we can use [look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) mechanisms here)

So something like this should work:

```
String replaced = originalString.replaceAll("(?<=\\s|^)(?=\\S)", "abc.");
```

But if `replacement` can contain `$` or `\` characters you will need to escape them with `\`, or with `Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement)` method.

```
String originalString = "foo bar baz";
String replaced = originalString.replaceAll("(?<=\\s|^)(?=\\S)", Matcher.quoteReplacement("abc."));
System.out.println(replaced);
```

Output: `abc.foo abc.bar abc.baz`

Comment: I'd use a shorter `"(?<!\\S)(?=\\S)"` pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes and +1 for this, but I will leave `(?<=\\s|^)` instead of `(?<!\\S)` since IMO it clearer shows what we are are after (negations may be more confusing).